# Extract elements within each component of a list in R

Tags: r

Given:

```
suf <- c( "IQ_IS-01_01_219_rgb",  "IQ_IS-01_03_218_rgb",  "IQ_IS-01_05_220_rgb" )
lsuf <- strsplit(suf,"_")
lsuf
```

I want to extract the 4th element of each vector
eg for the 1st one would be:

```
lsuf[[1]][3]
```

but the following does not work:

```
lsuf[[1:length(lsuf)]][3]
Error in lsuf[[1:3]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2
```

A solution would be using a for loop:

```
x <- rep(NA,length(lsuf))
for (i in 1:length(lsuf)){
  x[i] <- lsuf[[i]][3]
}
x
[1] "01" "03" "05"
```

Any R-elegant way to avoid the for loop?
ie, the correct form of

```
lsuf[[1:length(lsuf)]][3]
```

Comment: Check also `stringr::str_split_i(suf, "_", 4)`

Comment: I enjoy `vapply(lsuf, \(x) x[[3L]], character(1L))`. More intuitive than `vapply(lsuf, "[", character(1L), 3L)` in my opinion.

Comment: I do not delete the question because these solutions are not among those included in the suggested related questions.